How to access the attributes of a feasible solution in Gurobi Python model?
I have solved a Gurobi- Python model. Consider that for example during the optimization, this text is printed in the Run part: "Solution count 5: 131320 135861 179634 ... 192440"
For each of these feasible and optimal objective values, there are too many solutions.
for each of these 5 values, I want to access the variables of only one solution. (one solution with obj value=131320, one solution with obj value=135861 and so on).
I used this code:
"
nSolutions = model.SolCount
for e in range(nSolutions):
    model.setParam(GRB.Param.SolutionNumber, e)
    Obj = model.PoolObjVal
    y_value = model.getAttr('X', y)

"
the problem is that for every e, the y_value is the values of variable y of the Optimal solution not the solution which objective value is equal to Obj.
I want the y_value of that feasible solution not the optimal one.

Use the Xn attribute.  Eg, for Python
model.params.SolutionNumber=2
y_value = y.Xn

